# Problema na conversão de string em Timespan

Tags: c#, .net

No sistema que estou desenvolvendo um usuário me envia um `TimeSpan` via Post, porem quando pego a String que deveria ser o `TimeSpan` e aplico um `TimeSpan.Parse` ele da o erro:

> "Não foi possível analisar TimeSpan porque pelo menos um dos
>   componentes numéricos está fora do intervalo ou contém demasiados
>   dígitos."

A *string* está chegando assim para mim : 1416395054

Comment: Kaique, realizei um teste e converteu para "00:02:21.6395054" !

 var tempo = new TimeSpan(1416395054);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kaique, realizei um teste e converteu para "00:02:21.6395054" !

```
var tempo = new TimeSpan(1416395054);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: desculpe, não me atentei em transformar para int, já que na descrição do método aceita string, Muito obrigado pela ajuda